# Does $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=L$ imply convergence of $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=L<\infty $. Does this  imply convergence of $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)dx$?

I thought we can apply L'Hospital to  $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{-h}^{0}f(x)dx}{h}$ and   $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{0}^{h}f(x)dx}{h}$ and with the fundamental theorem we'd have $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)dx=2L$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but you can get it directly by realizing that $\frac  1 h \int_{-h}^{h} f(x) \, dx-2L=\frac 1  h \int_{-h}^{h} \{f(x)-L\} \, dx$ and using just the definition of limit.

Comment: Fundamental theorem works but without using L'Hospital's Rule. Each of the split limits is $L$ via Fundamental Theorem of Calculus so that the final result is $2L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. This is a direct approach without L'Hopital and just assuming that $f$ is integrable in a neighbourhood of $0$ (no need of continuity).

Since $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=L\in\mathbb{R}$, by definition of limit it follows that for a given $\epsilon>0$ there is $h>0$ such that for $|x|\leq h$, $$L-\epsilon\leq f(x)\leq L+\epsilon.$$ Hence, 
$$2L-2\epsilon=\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}(L-\epsilon)dx\leq \frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)dx\leq \frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}(L+\epsilon)dx=2L+2\epsilon$$
which implies that 
$$\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)dx-2L\right|\leq 2\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since you make a reference to “fundamental theorem” (of Calculus, I suppose), then my guess is that you are assuming that $f$ is continuous. Then, by the definition of derivative,$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_0^hf(x)\,\mathrm dx}h=f(0)=L$$and$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{-h}^0f(x)\,\mathrm dx}h=-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_0^{-h}f(x)\,\mathrm dx}h=f(0)=L.$$Therefore,$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{-h}^hf(x)\,\mathrm dx}h=2L.$$

Comment: Thank you. Would this still be valid without assuming continuity?

Comment: @H.Rappeport It would be more useful if you would tell me what is it that you *are* assuming.

Comment: Just one minor point. Define $f(0)$ to be $L$ to make it continuous at $0$. Then your answer applies with the result $2L$. So continuity is not assumed, but rather a result of the assumption that limit of $f$ at $0$ exists.